# How to multiply and divide times of the day e.g. 10:00 and 5:00 with overloaded functions?

Tags: c++

Okay, here is my edited code but now I get a Segmentation Fault (core dumped) everytime I compile. Where have I gone wrong? I'm not sure I "backtraced" it correctly but this is what I got out of trying:Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000109f0 in MyTime::MyTime (this=,
    h=, m=) at MyTime.cc:10
10      MyTime::MyTime(int h, int m){

```
//MyTime.h File
#include <iostream>

class MyTime
{
  public:

   MyTime(int h = 0, int m = 0);

   void Reset(int h, int m);

   void input();

   void output() const;

   MyTime operator + (const MyTime& t1) const;

   MyTime operator - (const MyTime& t1) const;

   MyTime operator * (const int& num) const;

   MyTime operator / (const int& num) const;

   bool operator == (const MyTime& t1) const;

   bool operator < (const MyTime& t1) const;

   bool operator <= (const MyTime& t1) const;

   int get_hours() const{return hours;}
   int get_minutes() const{return minutes;}

 private:
    void simplify();
    int hours;      // hours can be > 24
    int minutes;   // 0 <= minutes <= 59
};

    std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& fin, MyTime& t);

    std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& fout, const MyTime& t);
```

---

```
//MyTime.cc File
#include "MyTime.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// Constructor

MyTime::MyTime(int h, int m){
    hours = h;
    minutes = m;
}

void MyTime::Reset(int h, int m){
    hours = h;
    minutes = m;
}

void MyTime::simplify(){
    hours += minutes/60;
    minutes = minutes%60;
}

void MyTime::input(){
    char junk;
    cin >> hours;
    cin.get(junk);
    cin >> minutes;
    simplify();
}

void MyTime::output() const{
    cout << hours << ':' << setw(2) << setfill('0') << minutes;
}

MyTime MyTime::operator +(const MyTime& t1) const{
    MyTime tmp;
    tmp.hours = t1.hours + hours;
    tmp.minutes = t1.minutes + minutes;
    tmp.simplify();
    return tmp;
}

MyTime MyTime::operator -(const MyTime& t1) const{
    MyTime tmp;
    tmp.minutes = abs((t1.hours*60+t1.minutes) -
                                    (hours*60+minutes));
    tmp.simplify();
    return tmp;
}

MyTime MyTime::operator /(const int& num) const{
    MyTime tmp;
    tmp.minutes = hours * 60 + minutes;
    tmp.minutes /= num;
    tmp.simplify();
    return tmp;
}

MyTime MyTime::operator *(const int& num) const{
    MyTime tmp;
    tmp.minutes = hours * 60 + minutes;
    tmp.minutes *= num;
    tmp.simplify();
    return tmp;
}

bool MyTime::operator == (const MyTime& t1) const{
    return t1.hours == hours && t1.minutes == minutes;
}

bool MyTime::operator < (const MyTime& t1) const{
    return (t1.hours * 60 + t1.minutes) < (hours * 60 + minutes);
}

bool MyTime::operator <=(const MyTime& t1) const{
    return (t1 == (hours * 60 + minutes)) || (t1 < (hours * 60 + minutes));
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream& fout, const MyTime& t){
    t.output();
    return fout;
}

istream& operator >>(istream& fin, MyTime& t){
    t.input();
    return fin;
}
```

---

```
//main.cc File
#include <iostream>
#include "MyTime.h"

int main()
{
   MyTime t1, t2;
   int scalar;

   std::cout << "Enter a time:  ";
   std::cin >> t1;

   std::cout << "Enter another time:  ";
   std::cin >> t2;

   std::cout << "Enter a scalar to manipulate those times:  ";
   std::cin >> scalar;

   if(t1 == t2)
     std::cout << t1 << " is equal to " << t2 << std::endl;

   if(t1 < t2)
     std::cout << t1 << " is less than " << t2 << std::endl;

   if(t1 <= t2)
     std::cout << t1 << " is less than or equal to " << t2 << std::endl;

     std::cout << t1 << " + " << scalar << " = " << t1 + scalar << std::endl;
     std::cout << t1 << " - " << scalar << " = " << t1 - scalar << std::endl;
     std::cout << t1 << " * " << scalar << " = " << t1 * scalar << std::endl;
     std::cout << t1 << " / " << scalar << " = " << t1 / scalar << std::endl;

     std::cout << t2 << " + " << scalar << " = " << t2 + scalar << std::endl;
     std::cout << t2 << " - " << scalar << " = " << t2 - scalar << std::endl;
     std::cout << t2 << " * " << scalar << " = " << t2 * scalar << std::endl;
     std::cout << t2 << " / " << scalar << " = " << t2 / scalar << std::endl;

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is 10:00 times 5:00?

Comment: A TimeSpan divided by a TimeSpan is a scaling factor, and a scaling factor times a TimeSpan is another TimeSpan.  It makes no sense to multiply two TimeSpan-style objects by each other.

Comment: You're getting `this` and `t1` switched around in the comparison functions.

Comment: Also, the expression `t1 == hours * minutes` is using the implicit conversion from int to `MyTime` (leaving `minutes` defaulted to 0).  It's interpreted as `t1.operator==(MyTime(hours := this->hours * this->minutes, minutes := 0))`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, sort out the units, for example: time multiplied or divided by time make no sense.
Time added or subtracted to time gives time.
Time multiplied or divided by a number gives time.

Next, store time internally as minutes. Convert to hours and minutes for human consumption.

After that the rest will fall into place.

Answer (score 0):

For multiplication and division, MyTime::simplify does nothing if the time is at all formatted properly.  minutes/60 will ALWAYS be zero if 0 <= minutes < 60, because both minutes and 60 are integers, so it will round down.  Similarly, minutes%60 will be equal to minutes, as long as the same condition holds true.  Other than that, I agree with the comments that dividing one time by another is...strange, and something you should look into avoiding.

For your second issue, switch

```
(t1.hours * 60 + t1.minutes) < (hours * 60 + minutes)
```

to

```
(hours * 60 + minutes) < (t1.hours * 60 + t1.minutes)
```

So that the operator < for

```
this < t1
```

actually evaluates this on the left-hand side of the operator, as you've put it in your overload.

Comment: I know it's strange but it's an assignment for my class and that's what my professor asked or atleast thats the way I interpreted it. Here is the instructions he gave me: I have made a version of this class available in ~jdolan/cs2401/hw/hw1, which you can copy to your own directory with the cp command. In this example you will see that I have implemented four of the arithmetic operators, two of the Boolean operators and the input and output operators. They have all been implemented as friends.

Comment: Your assignment is to implement all of the operators without using friends. For the Boolean and arithmetic operators you should do this by making the operators members of the MyTime class, and for the I/O operators you should do it by writing input and output functions in the class that do the job of the operator, and then have the operator call that member function. The math and Boolean operators should use const to protect the object which is being used as the left-hand operand.
I have also asked that you combine the two constructors into a single constructor by using default arguments.

Comment: When you are done you should write an application that allows the user to enter two times, using the overloaded input operator, and a scalar, and then see all the math and 2 of the Boolean operators performed on those numbers.

Comment: Thos are all of the instructions did I do what he asked you think?

Comment: anybody I really need to turn this in.

Comment: Your professor mentions a scalar input to your test application - perhaps you're supposed to be able to multiply the time by a scalar? In that case, MyTime::simplify would be useful, because you could "overflow" the minutes field so that it would be greater than 60.

Comment: Yeah I think thats what he means but I don't understand that lol what is a scalar?

Comment: A scalar is a unitless number. For example, 10 minutes times 2 = 20 minutes. The scalar is the 2.

Comment: @user2513288: In your case, the scalar should have type `double`.

Comment: Ohhhh I'm so stupid I understand what he means now thank you for explaining that better!

Comment: One more question now I keep getting a seg fault error it also says SIGSEGV or something. I think I backtraced it and it says: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000109f0 in MyTime::MyTime (this=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xff3fff94>,
    h=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xff3fff98>, m=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xff3fff9c>) at MyTime.cc:10
10      MyTime::MyTime(int h, int m){